# Running/Debugging an app on Xcode as root user

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, root

I am writing an iOS application that uses low level raw socket (under a pure C routine).
Today I'm using the Xcode 4.6 to generate my application.

I need debug this app always on root level, but the simulator cannot run as root user.
I already try setuid (chmod 4755 or chmod u+s) on the gdb and on the binary app, but when it run, the debug doesn't run on root level.
I tried too configure the Xcode but without succcess, cause the option "Run as root" on debug scheme is disabled.

Has anyone developed an application that run on root level? In other words, that run as root on simulator/debugger?
How I can run on simulator (gdb, lldb, etc.. ) my app as root on Xcode 4.6 (OS Mountain Lion)?

Answer (score 0):

I think running things as root is typically not advised, and I think that you wouldn't be able to get special write access on an actual device, but you could try logging in as root on your mac and launching Xcode from there. I have not tried it, but it may enable the "Run as root" option

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported on iOS. This is an OS X-only feature. You cannot run as root on an iOS device.

(Old answer regarding OS X:)
I use this feature every day. You should not need to use setuid, just the Xcode "Run as root" flag. I suspect the problem is integrating with gdb, which was [deprecated in 4.6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc4_release_notes/xc4_release_notes.html). You should switch to lldb. (I also recommend switching to Xcode 5.1, but that's a separate issue.)